How to decomress a long byte stream using python?
I tried to decompress a long byte stream using python's zlib, but it always stopped at 65536.
My initial code was:
data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(rawdata)[14:])

The return data is correct, but trucated to at most 65536 bytes.
I then tried to search on Stackoverflow, and found several possible solutions, but none worked.
Solution 1, use zlib.decompressobj
data = zlib.decompressobj().decompress(base64.b64decode(rawdata)[14:])

It's truncated at 65536 too.
Solution 2, use Subprocess to open gunzip process to decompress
def gunzip(string):
    proc = subprocess.Popen('gunzip',stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    proc.stdin.write(string)
    proc.stdin.close()
    body=b''
    while True:
        output = proc.stdout.read()
        if len(output) > 0:
            body += output
        else:
            error_msg = proc.poll()
            if error_msg is not None:
                break
    return body

It doesn't work, the output is always empty (so is the body) and error_msg returns 1.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Your usage of zlib.decompressobj() is invalid: you never called .flush(), so an unknown amount of data might remain in internal buffers.  But even zlib.decompress() should have worked, there's no reason for it to stop at 65536 bytes.  I suspect that your compressed data is truncated or damaged.
